# FieldLabel inside a field

Tags: extjs, text, label

In EXTJS, is there anyway we can add a fieldLabel inside a field? Something like an emptyText but should not disappear on editing the field.

Answer (score 0):

As for as i understand you want to display some content inside field that can not be editable.
    What you can do is display content just besides the text field

```
           {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel:'<span>Scale <span class="help_text">your static content goes here</span></span>',
            labelWidth: 170,
            value: appName ,
            name : "appName",
            readOnly: true,
            allowBlank: false
         }
```

Comment: Getting a fieldLabel right next to the field is not what I want. Is there any way I can get the label inside the field and that should not be an emptyText.